# Violation of primary key code first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

This is the `Invoices` class:

```
public class Invoices
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Customers Customer { get; set; }
    public List<Payments> Payments { get; set; }
    public Double Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Boolean Payed { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the `Payments` class:

```
public class Payments
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public Int32 Quantity { get; set; } 
}
```

When I try to add an Invoices

```
Invoices addInvoice = new Invoices(customer, payments, total, date, payed);
Context.Invoices.Add(addInvoice);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this message:

[image: Violation products]

But I'm not trying to add a product. It is because I have a `Payments` list with a product for each payment? How can I resolve this?

Thanks to everyone who will answer this.

**Update**: I found why EF was trying to add again products.

I changed this line

```
pagamenti.Add(new Payments(new Products(idProduct, nameOfProduct, price)));
```

to this:

```
Products product = Context.Products.Where((p) => p.Id == idProdotto).First();
pagamenti.Add(new Payments(product, quantita));
```

And now it works properly

Comment: Are you setting the values for customer, payments, ...payed?

Comment: `Invoice` contains a List of `Payment`, `Payment` contains a `Product` and when you add a new Invoice you are giving it Payments and in turn a Product for each Payment.  So although you are adding a new Invoice, you are also attempting to add a Product that already exists in the DB

Comment: Yes xDJR1875 I haven't errors in code

And how i can resolve this problem? If i add an item like this: Products_Id List<Guid> it will auto key "constrainted"?

Comment: Maybe instead of a Guid use a Long autoincremental field on your database.

Comment: But if I use the the type of the key i don't resolve the problem. How I can add the payment without adding products?